# Radial component Dirichlet Boundary Condition ODE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Suppose I have a Dirichlet boundary problem defined on the unit disk. I have managed to separate variables -- solution $y(r,\theta)= R(r)\Theta(\theta)$ -- and reduce the problem into 2 1D problems. 
Now, I would like to solve the radial component numerically.

```
eqn = second order ODE for the radial component (only);
```

(I shall omit its explicit form here)

Then I tried defining (for some reason, Mathematica didn't like me calling the solution $R$, so I called it $y$ here. Also, I called $r, z$ here )

```
dcond = DirichletCondition[y[z] == c, 0 <= z <= 1];
```

(where c is a constant to be entered), and

```
region = 0 <= z <= 1;
```

Then to set things in motion,

```
solution[c_,x_] := y /. (NDSolveValue[{eqn, region, dcond}, y, z \[Element] {0, 1}] // Flatten) /. z -> x
```

However, when I run solution[0.78, 0.1] (for example, to pick 2 numbers for the arguments) , I get the error messages:

```
NDSolveValue::femnr: z\[Element]{0,1} is not a valid region specification. >>
NDSolveValue::femnr: 0.1\[Element]{0,1} is not a valid region specification. >>
```

Could anyone teach me how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely get what you mean here, but here is what I think is the answer here. Let this be some second order ODE for radial part of the equation:

```
eqn = -D[y[z], {z, 2}] + y[z] == 0;
```

The Dirichlet boundary conditions are specified in the region boundary, so maybe you mean:

```
dcond[c_] := DirichletCondition[y[z] == c, True]
```

This is the region:

```
region = Interval[{0, 1}];
```

and the solution

```
sol[c_] := NDSolve[{eqn, dcond[c]}, y[z], z \[Element] region]
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is perfect! I tried upvoting your answer but apparently I don't have enough reputation... Sorry and thanks again!